# MassTransit creates queues on azure service bus

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I developed a simple publish/subscribe example on a MassTransit and azure service bus as a message broker. The thing that I don't understand is that every time I start my solution MassTransit creates a queue per each service instance that connects to the bus :

[image]

I don't know what is the purpose of this. The queues are getting disposed after I stop services. MassTransit documentation does not give me an explanation for this. Maybe someone here knows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That queue is for the bus endpoint, which is created for every bus instance. It should automatically delete a few minutes after the bus instance is stopped.

It is used as a source for publishing, as well as a response queue for requests sent via the bus.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) do you have any article or sth that might give me a deeper insight to this ?